# How to reference realtime database in Firebase from Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, imageview, firebase-storage

I'm creating an app where people can see how their progress is on a course. So I'm trying to upload a progress bar image onto real time database in Firebase, I do this by uploading the image in Firebase Storage then copying the link and pasting it into a directory under each user's id. In Android Studio I'm finding it hard to reference the specific folder.

The Code:

```
ImageView imageView, imageView2;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
FirebaseAuth fAuth;
private DatabaseReference first = databaseReference.child("image");
private DatabaseReference second = databaseReference.child("image2");

// user name
TextView greeting;
private String userID;
private DatabaseReference reference;
private FirebaseUser user;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_12);

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Data");

    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    userID = user.getUid();
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    lLayout1 = findViewById(R.id.lLayout1);
    lLayout2 = findViewById(R.id.lLayout2);
    lLayout3 = findViewById(R.id.lLayout3);
    lLayout4 = findViewById(R.id.lLayout4);
    lLayout5 = findViewById(R.id.lLayout5);
    lLayout6 = findViewById(R.id.lLayout6);

    gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    //animations

    fabOpen = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fab_open);
    fabClose = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fab_close);

    rotateForward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_forward);
    rotateBackwards = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_backwards);


    //Initialize and assign variable
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);


    //Set Home selected
    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home);

    //Perform ItemSelectorListener
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.home2:
                    return true;
                case R.id.not2:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                            , Activity3.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    final TextView greetingTextView = findViewById(R.id.greeting);
    final TextView fullNameTextView = findViewById(R.id.fullName);

    reference.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            User userProfile = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

            if (userProfile != null) {
                String fullName = userProfile.fullName;

                greetingTextView.setText(fullName);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity12.this, "Something wrong happend!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    first.child(userID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String link = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Picasso.get().load(link).into(imageView);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }

    });
    second.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String link = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Picasso.get().load(link).into(imageView2);
        }
```

My Realtime database in Firebase

```
{
"Users" : {
"EzdWQOQ9W0UH5pscGF8nqviynMZ2" {: 
"email" : "sindanoo@outlook.com",
  "fullName" : "Eric",
  "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rent-to-own-93ff1.appspot.com/o/users%2Fuser_progress%2FIncomplete%20Bar.png?alt=media&token=638e1d13-7ce5-405e-b36d-6a1e46af97d4"

},
"UcbGBa0jlXhnMhT0UNPa2fT4nDH2" : {
  "email" : "sinddano@hotmail.com",
  "fullName" : "Sindano"
},
"y4MYqKRT3mYu4wokyQrhScIyasN2" : {
  "email" : "sindogg90@gmail.com",
  "fullName" : "Isaac",
  "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rent-to-own-93ff1.appspot.com/o/users%2Fuser_progress%2FIncomplete%20Bar.png?alt=media&token=638e1d13-7ce5-405e-b36d-6a1e46af97d4"
}
```

My User Class

```
public class User {

public String fullName, age, email, dateJoined, property, installment, homeValue;

public User() {


}

public User(String fullName, String age, String email, String dateJoined, String property, String installment,String homeValue) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.age = age;
    this.email = email;
    this.dateJoined = dateJoined;
    this.property = property;
    this.installment = installment;
    this.homeValue = homeValue;
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I have 2 ImageViews that I would like to display images from realtime database, but the way I referenced it in my coding is not correct, so I would want someone to help me reference it correctly.

Comment: In that case, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Thanks I will do so. I just don't know how to  attach the JSON file

Comment: There is an edit button right under your question.

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: So you only want to read the image of the logged-in user, right? If so, please also add the content of your `User` class.

Comment: Yeah exactly like you said, I've included my 'User' class.

Comment: But I cannot see any `image` field inside the class. Have you missed adding it?

Comment: this user class i copied it from my previous project to save time recoding, So I probably need to remove the fields and add `image` ? Or how should I correct it.

Comment: Yes, try that and tell me if it works.

Comment: Yes I finally managed to figure it out, thanks again.